# Start worker job from where it was left off with php resque?

Tags: php, batch-file, resque

Im batching queries in a php job to process.  I am curious if there is a way to pick up where the job left off at.

psdeuo code

```
function perform(){
    $batch_limit = 0;
    while($batch_limit<20){
       results = getstuff($batch_limit);
       dostuff(results);
       $batch_limit += 2;
}    

function getstuff($batch_limit){
   $results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $batch_limit, 2);
   return $results;
}
```

So for example if the arbitrary dostuff() function breaks on a result query of

`'Select * FROM table LIMIT 4, 2'`

Is there anyway i can pick up and execute

`'Select  * From table LIMIT 6, 2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the current limit to a simple key/value table and SELECT it at the beginning of `perform()`.

I always have a table for this kind of information, because it often comes in handy.
Just create a table with two columns "key", and "value". Key being VARCHAR and value being integer.

Then you insert your batch limit at the beginning of each call to getstuff()

```
function getstuff($batch_limit){
    $con->query("UPDATE keyvaluetable SET value=$batch_limit WHERE key='batch_limit'");
    $results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $batch_limit, 2");
    return $results;
}
```

And select it at the beginning of your perform()

```
function perform(){
    $result = $conn->query("Get value from before query here");
    if($result){
       $batch_limit = $result;
    }else{
       $batch_limit = 0;
    }
    while($batch_limit<20){
       results = getstuff($batch_limit);
       dostuff(results);
       $batch_limit += 2;
}
```

Comment: so i'd also have to have an insert for the batch limit number on success of a insert?

Comment: Before you get data and re-insert it, you simply write somewhere that you are now working on this batch. If it succeeds, the number will be overwritten. If it doesn't succeed, that batch will be the one you start at next time.

Comment: Thanks for that. Thats ingenious.